# AWS AppSync Error - AWSMobileClientStore.get(String) on null object reference

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-appsync, appsync-apollo-client

```
APPSYNC_ERROR: Attempt to invoke virtual method
```

> java.util.Map
>   com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClientStore.get(java.lang.String[])
>    on a null object reference

I am trying to inserting data in AWS table, But i got this error.
Can you help me to resolve this issue?

```
AWSAppSyncClient client = AWSAppSyncClient.builder()
                .context(context)
                .region(AppHelper.cognitoRegion)
                .serverUrl(AppHelper.SERVER_URL)
                .cognitoUserPoolsAuthProvider(new CognitoUserPoolsAuthProvider() {
                    @Override
                    public String getLatestAuthToken() {
                        try {
                            return AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getTokens().getIdToken().getTokenString();
                        } catch (Exception e){
                            Log.e("APPSYNC_ERROR", e.getLocalizedMessage());
                            return e.getLocalizedMessage();
                        }
                    }
                }).persistentMutationsCallback(new PersistentMutationsCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(PersistentMutationsResponse response) {
                    Log.d("NOTERROR", response.getMutationClassName());
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(PersistentMutationsError error) {
                    Log.e("TAG", error.getMutationClassName());
                    Log.e("TAG", "Error", error.getException());
                }
                }).build();
```

Comment: Can you provide more context? code & maybe schema?

Comment: I have follow this tutorial...
https://aws.amazon.com/pt/blogs/mobile/building-an-android-app-with-aws-amplify-part-1/

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/building-an-android-app-with-aws-amplify-part-2/

Comment: Do you know where exactly are you getting this error?

Comment: GraphQLCall.Callback<CreateTableMutation.Data> mutateCallback onFailure.

com.apollographql.apollo.exception.ApolloHttpException: HTTP 401

Comment: When i want to getLatestAuthToken()

Answer (score 5):

You need to initialize `AWSMobileClient` successfully before its usage.

```java
AWSMobileClient.getInstance().initialize(getApplicationContext(), new Callback<UserStateDetails>() {
     @Override
    public void onResult(UserStateDetails userStateDetails) {
        switch (userStateDetails.getUserState()){
            case SIGNED_IN:
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
                        textView.setText("Logged IN");
                    }
                });
                break;
            case SIGNED_OUT:
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
                        textView.setText("Logged OUT");
                    }
                });
                break;
            default:
                AWSMobileClient.getInstance().signOut();
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Exception e) {
        Log.e("INIT", e.toString());
    }
});
```

If `initialize` is successful, you will be able to retrieve the tokens through the `getTokens()` method.

Source: https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/android/authentication